# Parsing the output of SELECT INTO OUTFILE

Tags: java, php, mysql, load-data-infile, into-outfile

I'm trying to parse the CSV output of SELECT INTO OUTFILE. (The purpose is to bulk-load the data into an external NoSQL database; the bulk loader requires a specific file format so I'm writing a generator)

My main problem is the handling of escaped characters - specifically, the FIELDS TERMINATED BY character. MySQL does not seem to escape the delimiter when it occurs in a column value.

The export options of my query are as follows:

```
FIELDS
    TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES
    TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

I get CSV lines like:

```
"value1","some, value","another value","value3"
```

This breaks my CSV line parser that simply splits the line using the FIELDS TERMINATED BY character.

i.e. my parser produces the following column values:

- value1
- **some**
- **value**
- another value
- value3

"some" and "value" should have been parsed as a whole string "some, value"

What is the correct way to parse the output of SELECT INTO OUTFILE?

Anything else that I should worry about given the export options above? My code already handles the following cases within a column value:

(in exact order)

- Treat \N column value as NULL
- Replace \" with "

**Note:**

If anyone can provide the pseudocode of MySQL's LOAD DATA INFILE, that would be fantastic. The exact behavior of that statement is what I'm trying to emulate.

**Note:**

My parser is written in Java, but I can understand PHP much better

Comment: If you're using PHP use `fgetcsv` with the correct parameters. If you want to do it manually: the correct way to parse - I think - is obvious, you just have to actually parse it (read character by character).

Comment: Looks like a good match (i.e. supports enclosure). Do you know of an equivalent in Java?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/); although I had to write a special handler for NULL value which MySQL dumps as "\N". Fortunately, my schema does not have any nullable string field so I can safely assume that all occurrences of "\N" are NULLs.

Thanks to @Doge for reminding me not to reinvent the wheel :)